# Create Deep Link URLs for all platforms

Tags: android, ios, deep-linking

I know how to handle deep links in Android and iOS using intent filters, but I want to use same URL for all platforms.

How can I create a URL which can be handled by Android, iOS, and web without any of the library? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by using App Links on Android and Universal Links on iOS while maintaining your normal web site urls.

## **Setting Up Universal Links**

Once you have a particular domain registered for your website, you can configure your iOS app to open that URL using the app instead of the browser through Universal Links.

To do this, add your domain to the associated domains in your Xcode project.
[image]

Next, you have to host an *apple-app-site-association file* that is configured properly on your server https://.com/apple-app-site-association. It should look something like this.

```
{
    "applinks": {
        "apps": [],
        "details": [
            {
                "appID": "<teamId>.<bundleId>.dev",
                "paths": [ "*" ]
            },
            {
                "appID": "<teamId>.<bundleId>",
                "paths": [ "*" ]
            }
        ]
    },
    "activitycontinuation": {
        "apps": [
            "<teamId>.<bundleId>.dev",
            "<teamId>.<bundleId>"
        ]
    }
}
```

Once you have this setup you can test to see whether your Universal Link is valid using this [tool](https://branch.io/resources/universal-links/).

Now, your app should be able to process all of the same URLs that your website processes. You can see a full tutorial [here](https://blog.branch.io/how-to-setup-universal-links-to-deep-link-on-apple-ios-9/).

## **Setting Up App Links**

App Links are essentially Android's way of copying Universal Links so they operate in a very similar way. To set them up you start by adding intent filters to your manifest.

```
<activity ...>
    <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="http" android:host="yoursite.com" />
        <data android:scheme="https" android:host="yoursite.com" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Next, you host an assetlinks.json file on your web server as well at *yoursite.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json*. It should look something like this.

```
[{
  "relation": ["delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls"],
  "target": {
    "namespace": "android_app",
    "package_name": "io.branch.branchster",
    "sha256_cert_fingerprints": ["14:6D:E9:83:...
  }
}]
```

You should then be able to handle deep linking within your app. To see the full App Links tutorial click [here](https://blog.branch.io/technical-guide-to-deep-linking-android-app-links/).

## **Summary**

Using these two methods for Android and iOS you should be able to use the same exact links in all three cases of web, Android, and iOS. Of course this doesn't cover [deferred deep linking](https://branch.io/what-is-deep-linking/?_bt=204465566855&_bk=deferred%20deep%20linking&_bm=p&_bn=g&gclid=Cj0KCQjwhrzLBRC3ARIsAPmhsnX5w-KW3F-OtZdl9IvWVyB8yworeI2JE3zaKm3woiN-w2cMNGpNkc4aAq-UEALw_wcB) and will fail in some edge cases depending on the source that your user is linking from. For these reasons I recommend using a third party service like [Branch](http://branch.io) (disclaimer I work for Branch after being a long time user) or Firebase.